# Do i need connect router to master socket?

Tags: networking, home-networking, telephony

I have multiple telephone sockets in my house. When I connected router to master socket, everything is ok, but when I connected it to any other socket my internet is around  2.5 times slower.

Is it normal behaviour, or is it something wrong with wiring in my house?

Comment: Have you got [DSL filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSL_filter) installed?

Comment: @techie007 yes, i have filters, for both phone and router (as they are in different sockets)

Comment: @techie007 btw, if i didnt use filter, will be any difference between main socket and other sockets?

Comment: What is a "main socket"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz my bad, i ment master socket

Comment: @Hennes, i know i don't NEED to, but is it normal that affects signal so badly?

Comment: Have you replaced the filter on the faulty socket? Have had an electrician replace/check the socket?

Comment: @user99572isfine no i didn't replace anything, i just want to know is it fault, or expected behaviour

Comment: @user902383 What is a "master socket"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz master socket is where line enters property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have a setup similar to this one:

[image]

A **strong signal** enters the house at the ISRA point. If you split the line you get two weaker signals.

Traditionally the line is split and two filters are applied. One to block anything but the sounds/frequencies needed for an analog telephone. And one with a different frequency range for DSL.

That that I used thinner lines after splitting to indicate a weaker signal.

If the line which leads to the ADSL filter and the ADSL modem gets split a several times then its signal will also get weaker. It will either need more resends (in case a packet gets lots) or it will need to work at a slower speed.

Note that most of this is guess work. I will need more then 3 lines in a post to actually answer that.  (Also your DSL modem, switch and Wireless access point may be a single device).

Comment: thanks for answer, but i have more questions, if my line splits in N lines, but only 2 are in use, will size of N will affects network? and is it way to enhance signal, and how i can do it?

Comment: Yes. As long as more wires are connected the signal will enter those wires. Even if nothing is connected to them. Boosting the signal is possible, but can be expensive and a booster for a telephone part might not work for DSL. In part due to the different frequencies and because many boosters/amplifiers are one way devices while DSL is two way communication.  The usual solution is to connect the DSL modem where the signal enters the house. Then run an Ethernet wires from there. Obviously this is not alway practical with an all in one SOHO device.